# Handling multiple threads/outgoing http requests

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, network-programming

I am working on a Java/Spring web application that for each incoming request does the following:

1. fires off a number of requests to third party web servers,
2. retrieves the response from each,
3. parses each response into a list of JSON objects,
4. collates the lists of JSON objects into a single list and returns it.

I am creating a separate thread for each request sent to the third party web servers. I am using the Apache PoolingClientConnectionManager. Here is an outline of the code I am using:

```
public class Background {

    static class CallableThread implements Callable<ArrayList<JSONObject>> {

        private HttpClient httpClient;
        private HttpGet httpGet;

        public CallableThread(HttpClient httpClient, HttpGet httpGet) {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
            this.httpGet = httpGet;
        }

        @Override
        public ArrayList<JSONObject> call() throws Exception {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            return parseResponse(response);
        }

        private ArrayList<JSONObject> parseResponse(HttpResponse response) {
            ArrayList<JSONObject> list = null;
            // details omitted
            return list;
        }       
    }
    public ArrayList<JSONObject> getData(List<String> urlList, PoolingClientConnectionManager connManager) {
        ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonObjectsList = null;
        int numThreads = urlList.size();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);

        List<Future<ArrayList<JSONObject>>> list = new ArrayList<Future<ArrayList<JSONObject>>>();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(connManager);
        for (String url : urlList) {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            CallableThread worker = new CallableThread(httpClient, httpGet);

            Future<ArrayList<JSONObject>> submit = executor.submit(worker);
            list.add(submit);
        }

        for (Future<ArrayList<JSONObject>> future : list) {
            try {
                if (future != null) {
                    if (jsonObjectsList == null) {
                        jsonObjectsList = future.get();
                    } else {
                        if (future.get() != null) {
                        jsonObjectsList.addAll(future.get());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();

        return jsonObjectsList; 
    }
}
```

This all works fine. My question is in relation to how well this code will scale as the traffic to my website increases? Is there a better way to implement this? For example, by implementing non-blocking I/O to reduce the number of threads being created. Are there libraries or frameworks that might help?

At the moment, I am using Java 6 and Spring Framework 3.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you firing this callable? Where does the pool resides?

Comment: A thread pool is created in the getData method. A connection pool is created outside the getData method and passed in. I am creating an instance of the class Background and calling the getData method

Comment: You shouldn't use a new thread pool for each transaction. You would be better off creating a single thread pool at the start and just using it.

Comment: Indeed, don't create a pool per request. A single pool must exist in the app. Per request, you add the callable to the pool.

Comment: For the rest, it looks ok, but I would still do it asynchronously as I suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend to implement this as a synchronous service. Do it asynchronously. Get your request, pool the callables, and return a resource location where the client can later request the result.

You've got to be pooling this callables in an executor. Poll the executor in a background process and make avalable the results in the location you returned at the first request. Doing it this way, it would be easier to control your available resuources, and deny cleanly a processing requests if there aren't any more resources available.

Non blocking IO won't reduce the number of threads, it just delegates the "job" to another thread, in order for the service thread not to be blocked and to be able to receive more requests.

use REST.

Receive a POST request, and answer with something like this:

```
    HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Location: /result/to/consult/later
```

The client can then request the resutl at the given location. If the processing has not finished, then answer with:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
```

If its done then return a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` with the resulting JSON.

Comment: I am not sure if I explained the what I am trying to do very well. I am basically creating a mashup of responses from a number of third party web servers. If I have 10 third party servers, I am creating 10 threads (as I understand my code). I believe I could use non-blocking I/O to handle all 10 requests/responses in a single thread. I am just wondering is this the best way to do it or is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, I did understood the mashup idea. However, you're not creating 10 threads per se. Don't create a pool per request. Do single pool in your app, configure it with as many threads you want, and then put the callables generated per request in that pool. Callables will be handled by any thread available in the pool.

Comment: A pool per request is an expensive thing to do. Do the 10 request thing in a single callable.

Comment: I think you wantend to do requests to the 10 third party servers "in parallel", however, there is no such thing. You will be at most doing it concurrently, and I see no advantage in doing so because you'll still have to wait for an answer from all of them (unless you're implementing timeouts).

Comment: I want to do the 10 requests concurrently. If I do them all in the same callable, will they not be sent sequentially using blocking i/o and therefore take longer? That is why I am using 10 callables, one for each request, so the requests can be sent out concurrently.

Comment: Ok, granted. It would take longer. How are you handling requests timeouts? What happens if one of the 10 servers fails and doesn't answer? Will it block the request? do you retry? or, are you handling that case with a nice Not Available in the resulting JSON? Still, a pool per request is not advisable. Too many things can fail and you'll block the request. Generating child threads is expensive.

Comment: The worst thing that can happen is that your requests to the 10 servers get blocked. :S and non-blocking IO won't save the day. You'll consume all your resources with child threads.